Navigation bar color with WebView flutter
How can I change the navigation bar color in flutter with WebView?
I have this block at app start up:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: false,
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
));

It does work for all screen but the one with WebView. There the navigation bar is translucent and does not pick up the 'surfaceContainer' color:

you can do it with wrap this by scaffold and then give it app bar with systemOverlayStyle and backgroundColor also
if you can send minimal code we can help you more
